# Issue with retrieving elements using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I'm new to Flutter and trying to use a FutureBuilder in my project. I am trying to build a ListView with a list of elements from Cloud Firestore, so I'm using asynchronous functions to get the data and a FutureBuilder to give me a placeholder before it loads. Unfortunately, when I check snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done, the view will load before the list is completely populated, and I only get one of the elements that I am looking for.

I have tried implementing Future.delay to try to give the list time to populate. I have also tried printing along the way (marked in code below) to see if all of the elements are being pulled from the database (they are). I also tried initializing the Future in initState(), but it's possible it was implemented wrong.

```
class PlayersFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return PlayerFragStateChanged();
  }
}

class PlayerFragStateChanged extends State<PlayersFragment> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      ... //other items

      FutureBuilder(
        future: DataProvider().getPlayerList(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 20, top: 14),
                       child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                           Text(snapshot.data[position].firstName),
                          Text(snapshot.data[position].lastName),
                          Text(BoolDecider().decide(snapshot.
                              data[position].amta)),
              ),
             ],
            ),
           );
          },
         itemCount: snapshot.data.length
         ));
         } else {
          return Text('Waiting for data...');
         }


       ... //other items

     }
   }



class DataProvider {
  Firestore db = firestore();

  Future<List<MockPlayer>> getPlayerList() async {
    var result = await db.collection('Users').get();

    var dataList = List<MockPlayer>();

    result.forEach((doc) async {

      debugPrint(doc.get('First name')); //Prints EVERY name in the     database (as it should)

      dataList.add(MockPlayer(
          await doc.get('First name'),
          await doc.get('Last name'),
          await doc.get('AMTA Status'),
          await doc.get('Phone number'),
          await doc.get('email'),
          await doc.get('ID')));
    });

    return dataList;
  }
}

class BoolDecider {
  String decide(bool i) {
    if (i) {
      return 'Yes';
    } else {
      return 'No';
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the FutureBuilder to print multiple rows, but the length of the list in the AsyncSnapshot in FutureBuilder is only one, whereas it should be more than one.

Again, when I'm doing result.forEach, it iterates through every member of the database.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your forEach statement. forEach with "async" function completes after your future.connectionState is set to done. This is fixed by replacing:

```
result.forEach((doc) async {
      dataList.add(MockPlayer(
          await .. await .. await ..);
    });
```

with:

```
await Future.forEach(result, (doc) async {
      dataList.add(MockPlayer(
          await .. await .. await ..);
});
```

Also according to Pedantic Dart you should not forget to check for:
`snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError`.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks! Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another valid approach to this would be to replace

```
result.forEach((doc) async {
      dataList.add(MockPlayer(
          await .. await .. await ..);
    });
```

with

```
for(final doc in result) async {
      dataList.add(MockPlayer(
          await .. await .. await ..);
    });
```